# Plotting Boost Multi-Array with gnuplot

Tags: c++, arrays, boost, gnuplot, boost-multi-array

I want to plot a multi-array I have created with the Boost library. I keep getting stuck inside my gnuplot-third party library (added in order to plot). Im having trouble sending the correct references from my multi-array I think. Here is my code:

```
//Vector with linspace 
vector<double> points;
points = linspace(start_x, diff_x, 21);
//Pointer type and pointer
typedef vector<double> * point_ptr;
point_ptr p; //Pointer of type point_ptr.

p = &points; //Connect pointer to array


// Create a 2D array that is equal to meshgrid
typedef boost::multi_array<double, 2> array_type;
typedef array_type::index index;
array_type U(boost::extents[21][21]);
typedef boost::multi_array_types::index_range range;
array_type::array_view<2>::type myview = U[boost::indices[range()][range()]];

// Assign values to the elements
for (index i = 0; i != 21; ++i)
    for (index j = 0; j != 21; ++j)
        U[i][j] = (*p)[i]; 

gp << "set xrange [0:21]\nset yrange [0:21]\n";
gp << "set pm3d\n";
gp << "splot";
gp.send2d(myview);
```

Comment: You are probably talking about this library https://github.com/dstahlke/gnuplot-iostream/blob/master/gnuplot-iostream.h . Most likely the library doesn't understand the type you are passing. What error do (did) you get?